# Use (force) second JDBC connection to the same DB in the same thread

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, spring-data

I am using streaming in my query to MySQL DB. Works fine, until I issue another query during the streaming. That is fully OK and explained in the java.sql.SQLException:

```
Streaming result set com.mysql.jdbc.RowDataDynamic@16559dec is still active. No statements may be issued when any streaming result sets are open and in use on a given connection. Ensure that you have called .close() on any active streaming result sets before attempting more queries.
```

Since I really would like to make my second query in the middle of streaming, apparently I just need to use another DB connection for that.

So how can I force using another connection in the same thread?

I am using Spring Data with Hibernate

Please **do not** suggest fetching all at once or paging, that's not the point of the question.

Edits:

- streaming in my case is having a select from long table (millions of records), where next row is only transferred when it is requested. It is not streaming the file content. This is the article about that: http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html
- using another thread is a solution, but the question is about having in the same thread 2 connections at the same time

Program flow:

- run the query using stream (using connection 1)
- for every row from the stream
- - do something on db (using connection 2)
- streaming finishes, connection 1 closes

Comment: 1 thread = 1 query. 2 threads = 2 queries. i am pretty sure its that simple

Comment: You'll need to show code.

Comment: Hi, I added some edits, thanks

Comment: Are you sure there's not a chance to do everything on the database side? It's pretty inefficient (yes, even with streaming) to move data back and forth like that.

Comment: Kayaman, there are plenty of ways to solve the underlying requirement, but I would just find out whether it is possible to have this second connection using Spring Data and Hibernate

Answer (score 1):

So 1 thread with `{ 1. open conn, 2 - 8. asyncroneously stream, 9. close conn }, { 3. open or use conn, 4. query, 9. close or skip }`??

Try using a **connection pool** instead if the streaming is short enough.

Otherwise is this also a case where large streams are better stored as file name in the database (using a UUID for instance to generate file names). Then the streaming can be done outside of the database, and you could *throttle* the streaming to hamper a self-made DenialOfService.

---

***After question has been reedited.***

So the scenario is:

```
void f() {
    open conn
        do a java 8 stream
            g()
    close conn
}

void g() {
    open conn
    ...
    close conn
}
```

This is possible, with several ways of handling it: with a single global connection, with a connection pool, transactional or not cq. autocommit.

For queries I guess the most important is to close things. Try-with resources is ideal to not leak resources.

```
try (Connection conn = ...) {
    ...
    try (PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        ...
        try (ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery()) {
            ... the stream
        }
    }
}
```

The above closes also the ResultSet, which might have gotten you in troubles.

It is also quite thinkable you pass the stream on, it has access the result set.
As Stream is AutoCloseable too, you might need to tweak the code there. Or use a `CachedRowSet` instead of a ResultSet.

Sorry for this indeterminate answer.

Comment: Hi Joop, I added some edits to clarify the stream is not about files transfer, but iteration over large table.

Comment: Hi Joop, your answer is absolutely OK. One thing is, that I use Spring+Hibernate for DB access, one that is the question, how to realize your procedure using those frameworks? Anyway, +1

Comment: The procedures can be annotated and injected, even that for INSERTs a new transaction must be made. I am sorry, but I think my answer already is low quality. Best advice is to experiment yourself in dummy code like a _unit test_ to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you want to do.  I take it that you want to stream your data, transform somehow each item and then persist the result.  If that's the case, I believe that having a separate 'persist' method with annotation `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` should do the trick.

If you want more than one processing your stream (say, because you do some REST calls as part of it or, for some other reason you think that it might take long), you might want to consider pushing the streamed elements to a blocking queue and have multiple threads reading from there and doing whatever you need doing with each item.

Comment: Hi Ishi, I tried that already, no difference. I believe steering the transaction propagation is working on the same connection, it just says what to do with transactions, and does not create new connection (these are 2 different things)

Comment: Strange, it should work.  Are you sure the annotation was processed correctly?  Depending on how you have it configured, you might have to have the annotation a public method to make sure that hibernate 'decorated' your code correctly.

Perhaps try increasing logging level on hibernate transactions.  You should see that a new transaction creation is attempted (this usually requires a new connection --- I've never seen it succeeding without one, tbh).

Comment: Ok, if you are sure, than I will recheck that ;)

Comment: @Tomasz Make sure that the method with `REQUIRES_NEW` is called in a way that the annotation will be handled by Spring, so not in the same class as the method that does the streamin.